# Xcode: Array Count not Empty, but Array index is empty?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode

I recently notice that my app started to crash when loading the UIImageView*SideButton1, due to that "index 2 beyond bounds for empty array".

So I did NSLog to check whether I have the downloaded the data and put into the array correctly.

Below `NSLog(@"topbanner1 %lu ",sizeof(delegate.sidebannerDetailsArray))` returns 8, but `NSLog(@"topbanner1:%@",delegate.sidebannerDetailsArray)` return empty.

```
2018-01-04 12:18:03.320192+0800  topbanner1 8

2018-01-04 12:18:03.320429+0800  topbanner1:()

    NSLog(@"topbanner1 %lu ",sizeof(delegate.sidebannerDetailsArray));
    NSLog(@"topbanner1:%@",delegate.sidebannerDetailsArray);


    UIImageView * SideButton1 = [UIImageView new];

    [SideButton1 sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[delegate.sidebannerDetailsArray objectAtIndex:2]objectForKey:@"bannerImage"]]];

    }

    [SideButton1 setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [SideButton1 setFrame:CGRectMake(itemPriceLabel.frame.size.width-160,ItemTitleLabel.frame.size.height+ItemTitleLabel.frame.origin.y+10,180,45)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singletap1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openSideButton1URL:)];
    [ItemTitleView addSubview:SideButton1];
```

I am not sure why the count is 8 but there are no data in the array.
I tried to do this to work around but its not working:

```
if([[delegate.sidebannerDetailsArray objectAtIndex:2]objectForKey:@"bannerImage"] == NULL){
        [SideButton1 sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://xxxxx.com//sidebanners/sidebanner3.gif"]];
    }else{
    [SideButton1 sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[delegate.sidebannerDetailsArray objectAtIndex:2]objectForKey:@"bannerImage"]]];
    }
```

Any Suggestion?

Comment: `sizeof` is returning 8 because an `NSArray *` takes 8 bytes. `sizeof` has nothing to do with the number of objects in the array. Use the `count` property of `NSArray` to get the count.

Comment: ohh, Thank you so much!! Now I can work out a backup plan when count is 0. Thank you so much again for pointing out that I incorrectly used sizeof.